gauss-bonnet: confusion about boundary curve, and $ds$
Those are from the lecture note:
some notion definition
some intermediate formula
In short, it derives equation (1), but then suddenly jump to (2).
(1): $\int_{\Omega}K~dA ~=~ \int_{X^{-1}(\alpha)}(\theta'-\kappa_G)~ds$
(2): $\int_{\Omega}K~dA ~=~ (\sum_{i=0}^{k}\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} \theta'(t)~dt)- \int_{\alpha}\kappa_G~ds$
So, it must be the case that
(*): $\int_{X^{-1}(\alpha)}\kappa_G~ds ~=~ \int_{\alpha}\kappa_G~ds$
Where $\alpha$ is regular, smooth, closed, simple, arch-length curve on regular surface S, it represents the boundary $\partial\Omega$.
But I dont see why (*) true. Intuitively, $ds$ is a tiny length on $X^{-1}(\alpha) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\alpha \in S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$. For example, if we take $\kappa_G = 1$ (this possible, say, on sphere), then it said length of $X^{-1}(\alpha) = $ length of $\alpha$. But who know if coordinate chart $X$ is stretch the length or not?
My try:
$\alpha(t) = X(u(t),v(t))$, with $t\in [0,L]$
define $\eta = (u(t),v(t))$, then $\alpha(t) = X(\eta(t))$
And, from $\alpha$ arch-length curve, $|\alpha'(t)| = 1$ everywhere. Then, $|u'(t)X_u+v'(t)X_v| = 1$. By 1st fundamental form of isothermal coordinate $X$, have $X_u \perp X_v$ and $|X_u| = |X_v| = e^f$. Then, $|u'X_u|^2+|v'X_v|^2 = 1$, get $|u'|^2+|v'|^2 = e^{-2f}$. As this is precisely $|\eta'(t)|^2 = e^{-2f}$.
With $ds_\alpha = |\alpha'(t)|dt = dt$, and $ds_\eta = |\eta'(t)|dt = e^{-f} dt$. Then (*) is saying:
$\int_{t=0}^{t=L} \kappa_G e^{-f} dt = \int_{t=0}^{t=L} \kappa_G dt $
And I dont think it holds generally.

(1) was abuse of notation. It is incorrect. $ds$ here is not the element of arclength on the curve $X^{-1}(\alpha)$.
